# Forge Viewer Multiple PointClouds

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to use two pointclouds in the forge viewer, but once I add the second one the model disappears. I use an overlay for each pointcloud.

```
this.viewer.impl.createOverlayScene(this.options.layer);

this.markers.map((item,i) => {
  let pos = this.getPosition(item);
  if (!item.position) 
    this.markers[i]['position'] = pos;

  this.geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));
  this.geometry.colors.push(new THREE.Color(1.0, this.options.showIcon, 0.1));
});

this.pointCloud = new THREE.PointCloud(this.geometry,  new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
   side: THREE.DoubleSide,
   vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
   fragmentShader: this.fragmentShader,
   vertexShader: this.vertexShader,
   depthWrite: true,
   depthTest: false,
   uniforms: {
      size: { type: "f", value: this.size },
      tex: { type: "t", value: this.texture }
   }
}));
this.viewer.impl.addOverlay(this.options.layer,this.pointCloud);
```

I run this twice.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of the first line:

```js
this.viewer.impl.createOverlayScene(this.options.layer);
```

Forge Viewer maintains all overlay scenes (`THREE.Scene` instances) in a dictionary based on their names, so when you call `createOverlayScene` repeatedly with the same name, it will overwrite the earlier scene.

To solve that issue, I'd suggest that you only create the overlay scene once, when your viewer extension is loaded.

Comment: I create it with two different name, I get the same result if I were to add the two pointclouds into one overlay scene

Comment: Then make sure that you are actually creating two different geometries. From the code snippet you provided it looks like you may be appending the next set of points to the original geometry (on the line that says `this.geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));`).